# Release (envelope) cut out when AKsequencer repeats?

Tags: audiokit, aksequencer

I'm using `AKSequencer` to trigger `AKPlayer` using a midi note, to repeat certain audio files.

The question I have is that, the audio files are sometimes slightly **longer** than the designated midi durations, because there are release sounds included in the audio. `AKPlayer` doesn't seem to continue playing the files at the end of the sequencer duration - it immediately moves onto the new file triggered, so the audio files sound always slightly cut at the end. Slightly awkward.

Is there some sort of **option** such as 'mute after `AKDuration`' vs. 'Keep playing once it's triggered'? I am not even sure if this is AKplayer-related, or AK-sequencer-related issue. Thank you so much <3

Comment: Do you know the duration of the longest AKPlayer's playback? if so, I think you set the new duration to be the new sequencer length. can that work for you?

Comment: Thanks! I tried to adjust sequencer length (both sequencer.setLength and midinote's duration) but still, it cuts out the extra length of Audio file immediately after the set AKDuration.